# How to avoid "The form has become outdated" after login in separate tab

Tags: 7, forms

I've read [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25322/getting-the-form-has-become-outdated-error) and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/128982/2043) and I can't see how to apply that to my situation, so asking another question.

1. not-logged in user visits a page with a form on it.
2. User opens a new tab and logs in.
3. User switches back to their first tab and tries to submit the form.
4. Gets the outdated error.

How can I accept the anonymous form submissions once logged in?

In my application it's quite possible that the user has quite a few pages open in different tabs before they log in.

Answer (score 5):

The error is related to form CSRF protection, the error message comes from core form validation.

To avoid the error, it's possible to remove that CSRF token validation check in `hook_form_alter` e.g:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $id) {
  if (strpos($id, 'webform') === 0) {
    // Bypass per user CSRF token check and allow cache.
    unset($form['#token']);
  }
}
```

The caveat is, the form will no longer have default CSRF protection.

Alternatively, you might be able to detect the user has logged in (e.g custom [local storage set event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/defaultView/storage_event)) and reload the original page to refresh it as is.

Comment: Ooh, never come across the local storage event, good tip, thanks.

Comment: It's a shame this answer has not been accepted, at least to pay the effort put from David Thomas in giving good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because the form is outdated - the form was created for a "different" user. Drupal's request-forgery protection is there for a reason.

Many sites have this "problem" and the best way IMO to deal with it is for the site to take the submitted form (during validate) and re-present it with existing user-visible values filled in (but obvs. new form tokens etc).

It is then clear to the user that the form has been refreshed and they get a chance to try to submit as themselves.

I expect, though haven't tried, that the refresh action can be achieved using a form validate hook that you ensure is run first, and if it detects the form token is not valid it creates a redirect back to the form URL on the spot.

Alternatively, educate your users that filling forms in anonymously is not wise!