# Entityform - "The form has become outdated." error

Tags: forms, routes

I have an entityform that appears on a page, for some reason the form will not submit ...

```
// implement hook_menu

function foiagen_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/foiagen'] = array(
    'title' => 'Foia Generator',
      'description' => 'A foia generator form.',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('foiagen_form', 1),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
return $items;
}

// embed the form (it's an entityform).

function foiagen_form($form, &$form_state) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'entityform', 'entityform.admin');
  $entity_form_name = 'foia_generator';
  $render_estimate_form =
    entityform_form_wrapper(entityform_empty_load($entity_form_name), 'submit', 'embedded');
  $form['foiagen'] = $render_estimate_form;
  return $form;
}

function foiagen_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
}

function foiagen_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
}
```

I have tried to wrap my head around [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25322/getting-the-form-has-become-outdated-error) but cannot figure out where, once my form is rendered, filled and the submit button pressed the 'update' occurs that makes the input void...

I have seen the comment here and tried adding

```
 $form['#token'] = NULL;
```

to my 'function foiagen_form' that does circumvent the 'The form has become outdated.' error but leads to a blank page. Indicating that perhaps something else altogether is malfunctioning.

> following direction from answer came up with this:

```
function foia_generator_form($form, &$form_state) {
  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'entityform', 'entityform.admin');
  $entityform = entity_create('entityform', array(
    'type' => "foia_generator",
  ));
  $form = entityform_form_wrapper($entityform);
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Rather than `module_load_include()` you should use [`form_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_load_include/7) from a form constructor. (Not sure if that's actually a fix to the problem tho...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "The form has become outdated" error](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25322/getting-the-form-has-become-outdated-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have a hook namespace collision with [`hook_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7).

Although that might only be called if you're defining a node type, it's probably worth using a more specific function name for your form builder (e.g `function foiagen_generator_form`). Also make sure you're returning the form build array (array of elements), and not the rendered form in your form build function.

Comment: Form constructors always get `$form`, in Drupal 7; see [path_admin_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.admin.inc/function/path_admin_form/7). It is not different from validation and submission handlers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Thanks for the clarification, will keep that in mind!

Comment: Thanks, I came up with something that I actually understand from your pointers. Still having problems but will ask another question about that.